# laravel api handler how to order by a child column

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using [laravel API handler](https://github.com/marcelgwerder/laravel-api-handler) 
and I was wondering on how to send a request to order by a column from 'with' table

Here is my backend code

```
$query = Product::query();
    $query->company();
    $query->with('category'); $result=ApiHandler::parseMultiple($query);
    return $result->getResponse();
```

and the request-url

http://localhost/public/api/v1/product/view/0?&_offset=0&_limit=10&_config=meta-total-count,meta-filter-count&_sort=-category.category_name

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = Product::getModel()
->newQuery()
->select('products.*','categories.*')
->join('categories','product.category_id,'=','categories.id')
->orderBy('category.sort_order');
```

Something like that should do.